# jQuery.DataTables - fnAddData does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

After all written below data table isn't being populated with data:

HTML:

```
<table id="OrdersPending" class="row-border cell-border" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Login</th>
        <th>Route</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Time</th>
        <th>Points</th>
        <th>Done</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

JavaScript:

```
var ordersPending = $('#OrdersPending');
ordersPending.dataTable({
    "scrollCollapse": true,
    "paging": false,
    "bFilter": false,
    "bInfo": false,
    "jQueryUI": true
});
ordersPending.fnClearData();
ordersPending.fnAddData([['5', 'hjgjg', 'sglghsg', 'auiqri', 'afwkughfog', 'fefaf']]);
```

Comment: absolutely no messages

Answer (score 2):

I think you should delete one `[` in your code. I saw there's 2 `[`. Try to change it with this:

```
ordersPending.fnAddData(['5', 'hjgjg', 'sglghsg', 'auiqri', 'afwkughfog', 'fefaf']);
```

Comment: Sorry, I can't mark your reply. I just tested jQuery DataTables, after 1,5 years of not using it, and now it seems to work either with double brackets, or with single, and doesn't have `fnClearData` anymore. I'd like to delete my question because there is no issue anymore.